# Are operating system tags useful?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have a few tags for operating systems: [windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows)[macosx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macosx)[linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) (but no [solaris](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solaris) tag…). Each of these has only two questions, and I wonder: are operating system tags worth it?

On the one hand, there are some OS-specific questions that arise from time to time. So, having OS tags allow one to sift through them conveniently. On the other hand, Mathematica is designed to be cross-platform, and such issues appear very rarely (mostly, I think, about window decorations and keyboard shortcuts). Also, Mathematica users often try to write portable, and most questions involving OS-depend details actually give details for all three supported platforms.

- So, should we have OS tags?
- Should we close them as synonyms of a more general [os-specific](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-specific) or [platform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platform) or [system-specific](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-specific) tag? (I don't like any of these three names, but you get the idea)
- Should we simply remove these tags, as the questions would do fine without them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think, these tags are useful, for at least two reasons:

- Things like installation, administration, short-cuts, and also some Mathematica functionality are OS-specific. And people will appreciate separate tags, so that they can search directly, say for MacOSX, etc
- Even if the major part of Mathematica itself *is* cross-platform, many other things to which it can connect, and with which it can inter-operate,  either are not, or have platform-specific features.

Comment: True, and some functionality is **not** available on all platforms (e.g., sound recording on Macs), which might require workarounds using jlink/netlink etc.

Comment: Enabling Antialiasing is a good example of a very platform-specific quest.