# Is the wolfram-programming-cloud tag appropriate for a question that is specific to the WPC?

Tags: discussion, tagging

EDIT Preferred form of answer is "Yes/No, because...", rather than "Because..."  :)

Background:

- All my questions here arise from my use of WPC, and accordingly initially I tagged them [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud). I use no other WL platform and have no idea whether the questioned behaviour is shared by other platforms.
- People have repeatedly removed that tag saying e.g. "**your question was in no way specific to the use of the cloud, so I have removed it**" https://archive.is/lic8h#selection-963.12-963.95 EDIT: When I restored that instance, the same person removed it again https://archive.is/UUWMA
- Another has objected to the tagging e.g. "**there is absolutely no reason for you to stubbornly tag all of your questions wolfram-programming-cloud when they have nothing to do with it.**"  "**The fact you are using it is irrelevant. If I happen to be eating when I ask a question, I don't tag it sandwich, do I?**" https://archive.is/HuPrc#selection-831.327-839.7
- When I then omitted the tag from a question, a reader added the tag, saying  "**Added the Wolfram Programming Cloud tag because the described behavior seems confined to that platform, and not to desktop MMA 10.2**" https://archive.is/kGKZz#selection-345.0-345.131. Tags are surely parts of the question, not the answer.
- Another user said "**@ChrisJJ do us all a favor. ... If you don't have access to [the desktop version of *Mathematica*], leave a comment stating you have not been able to compare the two. This small extra step will help keep the peace**" https://archive.is/2l3E4#selection-849.150-853.37 I take this to suggest that in this forum for "*Mathematica* .... as well as related products", every question from a non-*Mathematica* user needs a note saying the behaviour has not been tested on *Mathematica*.

Note: This is not a RTFM issue. WL does exhibit *undocumented* variance in behaviour across platforms.

Note: Edited to replace links with links to archived versions.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  When there is not an established practice (which is exactly what this question should hopefully produce) we end up with mixed messages like you received.

Comment: Nice. Exactly what was needed.

Comment: A quick note, stackexchange archives _everything_. So, referencing things via the internet archive is not necessary.

Comment: @rcollyer Occasionally moderators clean out the comments that are not on topic. Meta discussions in particular risk being deleted like that. I'm talking here of SE in general, I've seen it happen many times at for example workplace.SE which is more prone to off topic chatter than we are.

Comment: @Pickett, true, but if push comes to shove, mods can see deleted comments, and we can show the original flow of conversation if need be.

Comment: @Pickett also, as a site, we are very lax about comments. So, they don't get deleted as often as you'd think, here. :)

Comment: @rcollyer *I* know that, but the OP has no idea how this site works (based on his criticism here and elsewhere). So just saying.

Comment: @Pickett absolutely. just making sure we're all clear.

Comment: @rcollyer "stackexchange archives everything. So, referencing things via the internet archive is not necessary." Referencing things via the internet archive is necessary.to avoid links to questions showing something different, as already happened in discussions about off-topic markings that were since rescinded.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I know you believe that, and the evidence would seem to suggest it, but dig a little deeper. All the edits are archived along with who made them, which you are aware of by the links you made, and deletions can be accessed by the moderators. Also, there’s [data.se] which gives you query access to the underlying database. The info is not going anywhere. On this site, we are not adversarial (I make no claims about [so]), and we genuinely wish to help you. (Some of it is intended to be gentle instruction, like the links.) Please give us the chance to do so.

Answer (score 20):

I feel the best way to deal with potential platform dependencies is to mention your platform *in the question* and don't use the platform name as tag unless you are sure the platform plays a role. We can only use 5 tags and if everyone is going to tag his OS and version number, regardless of relevance, differentiation will be hugely impacted.

If you own different platforms you can do the experimentation wrt system specificity yourself; if not, wait until community members have checked this. We do this for the "bugs" tag as well.

Related questions can be found in the links below.  In the first there are not an awful lot of reactions but I'd say the gist is that system tags are useful if the issue is system specific. [I'd like to add: But only then].

- [Are operating system tags useful?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/are-operating-system-tags-useful)
- [How should we tag version-dependent questions?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-should-we-tag-version-dependent-questions)
- [How should we tag longstanding bugs that have been fixed?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1361/)
- [Standard header for bugs-tagged posts, for easy searching](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching)

Comment: A similar discussion about version tags [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-should-we-tag-version-dependent-questions).

Comment: Many of us used to tag bugs with the version number. This procedure had some problems so we now use a more or less standard header formalized in [this Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching) and don't tag with a version anymore.

Comment: Recommended putting all these links in the answer proper.  And I'd include this one too: [(1361)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1361/121)

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow. One-finger editing on an iPad is not really a party.

Comment: I'll do what I had in mind; you can revert or correct later if needed.

Comment: "don't use the platform name as tag unless you are sure the platform plays a role" That's quite a departure from stackexchange custom, and this forum's advice http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/tagging , esp. "A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question." I'm not saying it's a bad idea, just that it sounds more like a proposal for change rather than a description of current usage.

Comment: It is in no way a proposal, @Chris. This was community consensus, agreed upon before you started asking questions here. Again, *less is more*. If you're not sure, don't add the tag yourself; let it be added after community vetting.

Comment: "This was community consensus" Perhaps it was then, but I think you'll find newcomers will go by http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/tagging "What are tags, and how should I use them?" which makes no mention of this.

Comment: "Again, less is more." No, less is not more when it comes to '*What are tags, and how should I use them? A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.*' "If you're not sure, don't add the tag yourself" I am sure that WPC is the topic of my question. Yet still people remove my tag apparently because they disagree with the question ... and they don't even provide an answer.

Comment: IMO: WPC can only be the topic of a question if it conceivable that "Mathematica 10.2" could be the topic of a similar question. If you are asking about the behaviour of the Wolfram Language, then WPC is not an appropriate tag. Analogy: if you were asking a question about Swift, you wouldn't tag a question "xcode". If you think it's really a WPC problem (that is, a problem not with your use of the Wolfram Language but with how the WPC interprets your WL code, or a question about how the WPC works which is not really a question about the WL) then the tag is appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisJJ "I am sure that WPC is the topic of my question" - but surely "plotting" is a better description of the topic of your question, which was about a plot?

Comment: @chrisjj In order for all of us to get an idea of what the community thinks about this you might consider writing a separate answer voicing your opinion about the issue at hand. In that way, people can vote about this and policy can be settled based on the results.

Comment: @Patrick "*If you are asking about the behaviour of the Wolfram Language, then WPC is not an appropriate tag.* " Patrick, if you read the question a but more carefully, you'll see it says "**that is specific to the WPC**". "*If you think it's really a WPC problem*" I do. It is really a WPC problem for me because (as I said in the Q) WPC is all I am using. "*(that is, a problem not with your use of the Wolfram Language but with how the WPC interprets your WL code*". No, that is not what "that is". As the Q says "**I have no idea whether the questioned behaviour is shared by other platforms.**"

Comment: @blochwave "but surely "plotting" is a better description of the topic of your question, which was about a plot?" OK, so you're complaining I didn't add a plotting tag. Fine. That's got nothing to do with whether the platform tag is appropriate.

Comment: @Sjoerd "people can vote about this and policy can be settled based on the results." I've been told here that your way is "**community consensus, agreed upon**"? Is that true or not? Also your answer statement has evaded answering the question. Could you please say if it is a Yes or No to the Q. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, would you really tag a similar C question "gcc" or "ubuntu", because those were what you were using to compile/view the results of the program? If your mind is anything like mine, it wouldn't even have occurred to you to tag a C question with the specific compiler you were using *unless you thought your question was compiler-specific*. In that situation, don't you agree it would be standard to post your question about C, and subsequently for people to tell you it was actually a gcc question (if it were)?

Comment: @Patrick C is a standardised language with good reproducibility across platforms. WL is not. "*unless you thought your question was compiler-specific.*" My WL-WPC questions *are* platform specific. I am specifically asking for a solution for WPC.  Whether the **answer** applies on other platforms is of no interest to me.

Comment: @Patrick, Would you object to someone tagging a C question "gcc" if they were interested only in answers for gcc? Would you then delete that tag, and then when the author restores it, delete it again? As has occurred on this forum to my WPC tag?

Comment: @ChrisJJ, I would object to that, yes. I would delete the tag, and if the author restored it, I would see if they had any reason for thinking that the issue was related to GCC. If they did not have such a reason, I would once again delete the tag. "WPC" is there as a tag so that people can search for issues related to the WPC, not so that people can search for issues which happen to manifest on the WPC as well as other places. Remember, StackExchange is there to help people in the future as well as you; having everything labelled "gcc" or "clang" is useless to people who are trying to learn C.

Comment: @Patrick "**I would object to that, yes. I would delete the tag, and if the author restored it, I would see if they had any reason for thinking that the issue was related to GCC.**" Sorry, but the tag qualifies the question, not what ever you (and everyone else NOT providing an answer) think is the "issue". The fact the user is using only WPC and is asking only for WPC is relation enough to WPC. If you want to ask the same question for all platforms, then post it yourself rather than interfering with the existing question.

Comment: And Patrick, if you have a straight answer to this question, inc. Yes or No, please post it.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: I'm sorry, but very-preliminary results suggest consensus is against that view, judging from the upvotes on my comments. Tag status is determined by the question, not by the intentions of the poster. Questions are answered on StackExchange so that the answer may help anyone with the same problem in future, not specifically for your assistance, so tagging is in principle determinable just by seeing the question, independent of the poster. I'll write this into an answer - thanks for the prompt.

Comment: @Patrick "Tag status is determined by the question, not by the intentions of the poster." The question is nothing but the intention of the poster. Therefore the tag status being determined by the question means it is determined by the question. If you don't like the question, ask your own.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: observe the existence of the "too localized" reason for closing, which to me is clear evidence that the intent of StackExchange is to provide a place for the answering of questions in such a way as to help more than one person. I'm going to duck out of this conversation now, as I'm getting heated up.

Comment: See http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/where-is-the-record-of-the-agreement-referred-to-here

Comment: @chrisjj Unfortunately for some perhaps, the world is not black or white. I'm not saying yes or no, because the issue needs more nuance than that. If the issue is very specific to WPC by all means add the tag. But if it isn't or if you are not able to make sure it is, don't.

Comment: @Sjoerd "If the issue is very specific to WPC by all means add the tag. But if it isn't or if you are not able to make sure it is, don't." Issues aside, I'm asking about questions. If my question is about how to achieve a certain result on WPC and no other platform, then should I add the tag?

Comment: @ChrisJJ that clearly depends on what the question is. I wish there were a clear answer, but that's the truth. If it deals with the display, then I think WPC is clear. As to what the language can do, it is much less clear. You are within your rights to not accept an answer that does not address it, though.

Answer (score 10):

No to the question you intend to ask; yes to the question you actually asked.

The tag [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) is for questions which are related inherently to the WPC. If your question is about the Wolfram Language, whether or not you access the WL via the WPC, then it does not warrant the tag. If your question is about something you think is a bug in the WPC, then it should have the tag. If your question is about the WPC interface, then it should have the tag. If you would have the same question while using Mathematica (referring to the desktop program), then it should not have the tag, except under weirdly specific circumstances like a bug which manifests differently in both environments.

The reasoning behind this is that the tags are there to help filter the questions for people in the future, and for people who are currently trying to answer questions. [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) questions are expected specifically to be about the WPC, in the same way as [integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) questions are expected specifically to be about integration; that way, people with the right expertise can find relevant questions. For instance, if I used the function `Integrate` as an example to demonstrate a general principle about `UpValues` in Mathematica (and there was nothing about my answer that inherently used `Integrate`), then the question would not warrant the tag [integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration), because the main idea of the question would really be `UpValues`. Likewise, the fact that I use the WPC to formulate my Wolfram Language programs is not enough to justify the [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) tag. It is unhelpful to future visitors to use that tag in this context, because the question isn't really about the WPC at all.

Imagine you were an expert on the ins and outs of the WPC, how to use it to its fullest potential, and all its interfacing questions. You search for the [wolfram-programming-tag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-tag) tag with the intention of providing specialist knowledge, and are presented with thousands of questions about the Wolfram Language, almost none of which actually require knowledge about the WPC to answer. I think one, in the position of WPC expert, would justifiably be annoyed in that situation.

Comment: "No to the question you intend to ask; yes to the question you actually asked." The question I asked is the question I intended to ask. "If your question is about the Wolfram Language, whether or not you access the WL via the WPC, then it does not warrant the tag." Sorry, that does not accord with the stated policy of this forum http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Comment: I may come back to this tomorrow; as commented above, I'm leaving this for now.

Comment: And on "If your question is about the Wolfram Language, whether or not you access the WL via the WPC, then it does not warrant the tag." a point that seems to have got missed despite my saying it many times: **WL on WPC is not the same as WL on other platforms**. There is variance, both declared and not declared in docs.

Comment: @ChrisJJ that is mostly incorrect. The exceptions surround the need to display on a webpage vs desktop computer and to execute arbitrary code in a cloud environment. The rest is WL and is run by the same kernel (the execution) engine as found on the desktop.

Comment: @rcollyer What makes that statement correct is the exceptions. "*The rest is WL and is run by the same kernel (the execution) engine as found on the desktop*" Evidently not e.g. try SocialMediaData[].

Comment: @ChrisJJ congrats! You found something that is different. Now, I don't know why it is excluded, but it is in essence a loaded library. Have you never worked on a platform where a library was unavailable? My post stands. The execution engine is identical with a few exceptions, and the major difference is in the display.

Comment: @ChrisJJ the question of what functionality is not available on WPC is a legitimate one, and should be asked. I think it would be valuable information. Please ask it on [main].

Comment: @Chris, as rcollyer says, that would be a well-received question on the main site should you choose to ask it; just… ease up on the 'tude, okay?

Comment: @rcollyer "it is in essence a loaded library" So what? Such implementation details is irrelevant. What is relevant is that WL differs across platforms.  "The execution engine is identical with a few exceptions" Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @ChrisJJ your misunderstanding makes sense now. You're coming at this from other languages where the key-words are immutable constructs, such as `auto`, `class`, and `return` in c++. Put this out of your mind. In Mathematica, unless the symbol is `Locked` it can be overridden. So, the functionality that comes with WL cannot be considered key-words in any sense remotely like any language you've likely [encountered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7591/52). For example, if I create ``System`bob`` it is indistinguishable from the default WL, and yet, should it be considered part of WL?

Comment: @ChrisJJ (cont’d) So, when I say the language is the same, except for the cloud constraints, I mean it. I’m not being facetious. Only what is allowed (in the computer system sense) has changed, but the language remains the same. As I said, I do not know why  `SocialMediaData` is excluded, but a surprising amount is allowed, such as `URLSave`. I’m curious as to what else is excluded.

Comment: @rcollyer "So, when I say the language is the same, except for the cloud constraints, I mean it." Show a list of these "cloud constraints" and that statement might actually be useful. Until then, it isn't. "Only what is allowed (in the computer system sense) has changed" So you know what's changed? " I’m curious as to what else is excluded" So you don't know what's changed. Thanks anyway for the suggestions.

Comment: @rcollyer "your misunderstanding makes sense now. You're coming at this from other languages where the key-words are immutable constructs" Nope. WL's mutability is a matter totally separate to the variance of WL's behaviour across platforms.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I'm done bothering. No matter what I say, you're going to continue believing what you wish. Good day.

Answer (score 8):

**Is the [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) tag appropriate for a question that is specific to the WPC?**
No. That would be selfish. The intent of this site is to house a knowledge repository that would be helpful to future users. Otherwise there would be no point in, for example, closing duplicate questions. Similarly, the many, who use only plain old *Mathematica* don't tag every question as such.

**Is the [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) tag appropriate for a question *on an issue* that is specific to the WPC?**
Yes. But, until you have verified that, there's no grounds to include the tag.

**Edit:** Let me also quote the rules, to which you appeal so.

> - If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`, and `[best-practices]`, are not helpful by themselves – they do not communicate anything about the content of the question.
> - If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. For example, the meaning of the tag `[subjective]` is, itself, subjective; the same is true for tags like `[best-practices]` and `[beginner]`. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? Use only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective definition.

[wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) not only is insufficient as the only tag (just like *Mathematica*-related questions almost never have a [mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) tag, but always have some like [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation)), it is clearly perceived differently, than you take it to be perceived. That is, if I would for some reason click on [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud), I would most certainly not be searching for problems of users, that happen to have access only to WPC. I'd likely be searching for subtleties specific to WPC.

Comment: "That would be selfish. The intent of this site is to house a knowledge repository that would be helpful to future users." - +1 just for that.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. thanks for the formatting. Post my edit I realized, that there are no Mathematica tags :D

Comment: We actually blacklisted that tag during the first few weeks of this site, yes. :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. it took that long? I thought it was within the first few hours.  :)

Comment: @rcollyer, it was so long ago that hours and weeks seem the same. In contrast, these days an hour can sometimes feel like a week, and less often, a week can feel like an hour. ;)

Comment: LLlAMnYP "it is clearly perceived differently, than you take it to be perceived." So where should one go to discover the common perception of a rarely used tag? I would have thought the tag wiki, but this tag has no content there.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "there are no Mathematica tags" Astonishing. How does that make it possible to follow your advice for correct use of the WPC tag when the platform is not WPC but Mathematica?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "No. That would be selfish."  And would accord with http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. This site is all about getting answers." Seems there's a sight disjoint between that and, Help's "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Mathematica". Perhaps one needs to ask who the Ask a Question form is primarily for. The guy asking the question? E.g. me. Or the "we" building this library? E.g. you.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I think you got the answers to most of your questions here even if you may not like some of them, so do read it out of the multiple answers you got and *deal with it*. Now specifically to address your comments: 1) Go edit the tag wiki if you aren't satisfied. 2) Because "default platform". Most questions here are from users of Mathematica proper. We do have version tags for version-specific issues. 3) I'm getting kinda' tired of constant appeals to generic sites over which we have little to no control. Go complain on meta.SE about that *(cont'd)*

Comment: No, we are *not* building a database of *every* question on *Mathematica* (and related products). It seems to be the default "philosophy" of SE (*every* question about XXX should be on this site), but this community decided that we don't need a wealth of questions such as "how do I multiply `a` and `b` in MMA" and "how do I add `c` and `d` in WPC". For this reason we have the custom close reason "simple mistake or easily found in the documentation". Anyway, regarding your actual question. **This site is not your personal coach** *(cont'd)*

Comment: You bring up an issue, the community researches *the issue* rather than researching *you*. The question is (should be) valuable without the asker. For example, we delete questions about bugs/errors that only seem to happen on the asker's machine  and cannot be reproduced. *Just questions and answers, no distractions...* Also, from a completely different angle, but regarding your usage of tags, I might point out, that wikipedia has an article on Cerenokov radiation *(cont'd)*

Comment: But it doesn't have separate articles on Cerenkov radiation in water, Cerenkov radiation in oil, Cerenkov radiation in some other optically dense medium etc. To sum everything up, it looks to me, as if the WPC-tag question has been answered. **Separating that from follow-up questions**, if something's not clear, feel free to ask. Regarding the follow-up questions, which all seem to be along the lines of "but this seems to conflict with the help pages which I liberally interpret as XXX" *(cont'd)*

Comment: It has again been clearly stated several times, that the help is not perfect, sometimes there's some ambiguity, but the community's policy is this or that. It's all good and well to make mistakes, especially so when there's some ambiguity in some help pages. It isn't ok to flip out and say "I don't give a crap, what you mods say, because it isn't explicitly written on page XXX".

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "1) Go edit the tag wiki if you aren't satisfied." After all the flak I get for just asking questions? No thanks.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "No, we are not building a database of every question on Mathematica (and related products)" Then evidently you are not the we referred to in the Help "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Mathematica". Whoever they are, perhaps they'd like to chip in.

Comment: Chris, are you capable with *dealing* with imperfect documentation? I'm sorry, but it's not going to change without a very serious reason. Over parts of it the mods here have no control.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "you capable with dealing with imperfect documentation" I see you disagree with the documentation. I don't see that's due it it being imperfect.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I disagree with *your interpretation* of the documentation. Also I disagree with thoughtless attempts to apply the standards of SE in general to any given community. Although parts of the general documentation of SE leak into the documentations of each specific community, however often the mods have no control over that. Nonetheless, every community is run not by SE employees, but by the specific community itself. This principle, IMO, prevails over whatever general approaches SE has. Thus, if the community chooses to operate in a way, that in parts conflicts *(cont'd)*

Comment: with the overall principles of SE, the rules set by the community should have precedence over the rules set by SE. Now, as far as interpreting the rules, law is not a simple subject. When talking about laws of a given nation, it is sometimes unclear, what interpretation to go with. In that case, it is usually up to the constitutional court or the supreme court to publish its own interpretation, which is the only correct one. Drawing parallels to the community here, it is the community elected mods, that do the arbitrage. *(cont'd)*

Comment: Whatever interpretation the mods present is final and most certainly overrules whatever you yourself have read out of the help pages. The "nice" way to go about it is to admit "sorry, I had read that differently, I'll not make the same mistake in the future, maybe you could make the wording of such and such paragraph a bit clearer". You however, have created several posts which sound like demands along the lines of "you're giving me crap, change that page immediately, otherwise I wish not to hear of what you mods have to say".

Comment: Pointing out the exact words that have mislead you to believe otherwise would also be helpful, rather than just distributing links and saying "your opinion is crap and this page says otherwise".

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "I disagree with your interpretation of the documentation" Your "No, we are not building a database of every question on Mathematica (and related products)" is a disagreement with the literal documentation "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Mathematica". No interpretation by me.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "Although parts of the general documentation of SE leak into the documentations of each specific community, however often the mods have no control over that." Do the mods have control over the "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Mathematica" with which you disagree?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP "You however, have created several posts which sound like demands along the lines of "you're giving me crap, change that page immediately" That's an outright misrep. I have never said anything like "change that page immediately" or in any way demanded a page change. What I have done is highlight discord between the behaviour and statements of mods and the "rules".